# XML Parsing for Mediawiki link

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7, mediawiki-api, wikitext

I have this link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=panadol&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

I need to get the content inside  tag. so I used this code

private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

```
                    WebClient wwc = new WebClient();
                    String xmlStr = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=" + medName + "&prop=revisions&rvprop=content";
                    wwc.DownloadStringCompleted += wwc_DownloadStringCompleted;
                    wwc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(xmlStr));


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't search for medicine!\nCheck the internet connection.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

    }
```

also calling this method.

```
                XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
                var entry = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                var xmlData = new xmlWiki();
                var g = entry.Element(ns + "rev").Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But I am getting Null reference exception when the code executes "var g = entry.Element(ns + "rev").Value.ToString(); "

Please any help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rev` is not the child of root of tree. This is the path to it:

```
api
  query
    pages
      page
        revisions
          rev
```

You can use `.Descendants()` to reach it.

```
var entry = XDocument.Parse(html);
var g = entry.Descendants("rev").First().Value;
```